# Git force commit and push , when getting "nothing to commit"

Tags: git

I need to force commit and push file , as each commit trigger some external event in the application , this is when the file i committing is same as in the remote 
now i do :

```
git automation commit -am "testing"
```

and it gives me :

```
On branch develop
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

it cancel the commit ...
how i force the commit and push ?
so it will update the file in the remote

Answer (score 6):

To add an empty commit... `git commit --allow-empty -m "testing"`. Then push normally.

Side note, you may way to look into other means to trigger an event. This will clutter your history.